# MySQL sliding window dynamic intervals?

Tags: mysql

Say I have table with 2 columns `start` and `end` timestamps

eg.

```
start, end
2023-09-04 11:14:12, 2023-09-04 11:24:27
2023-09-04 11:20:17, 2023-09-04 11:34:37
...
```

Is it possible to specify dynamic interval based on `end - start` in the sliding window query?

Imaginary query like:

```
SELECT created_at , 
    COUNT(*) OVER w AS cnt
FROM records
WINDOW w AS (
ORDER BY created_at
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL (ROW.end - ROW.start) PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW);
```

<s>The goal is to work out how many records overlapped with `start` and `end`</s> The goal is flawed as it only finds out how many records overlapped with the current record. However the question still stands for dynamic intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a limited form of expression in a frame start or end.

The rules are documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html

> For *expr* `PRECEDING` (and *expr* `FOLLOWING`), *expr* can be a `?` parameter marker (for use in a prepared statement), a nonnegative numeric literal, or a temporal interval of the form `INTERVAL` *val* *unit*. For `INTERVAL` expressions, *val* specifies nonnegative interval value, and *unit* is a keyword indicating the units in which the value should be interpreted.

In other words, the interval must be a *fixed* interval, not a different interval depending on values in each respective row.

Besides, I think the example you show (if it had worked) would not reliably count the rows that overlap the current row, unless `created_at` is constrained to be between `start` and `end`.

I think for your case, you would do better to use a self-join:

```
SELECT r1.created_at,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM records AS r1
JOIN records AS r2 ON r2.created_at BETWEEN r1.start AND r1.END
GROUP BY r1.id;
```

Assuming `id` is the primary key of the table.

Comment: Yes you are right I realised it's not the correct logic to do overlapping count over all records

Comment: Hence I asked another related question, can you have a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356497/mysql-is-it-possible-to-group-by-duration-intersection