# MySQL is it possible to group by duration intersection?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a set of phone call data which has `start` and `end` timestamps, I need to work out the most concurrent calls within a month, so the call "duration"s need to overlap, unfortunately I don't think I can use "sliding window" as it only works with single field.

eg.

```
start, end
...
2023-09-04 11:14:12, 2023-09-04 11:24:27
2023-09-04 11:20:17, 2023-09-04 11:34:37
...
```

Instead of fetching the whole set into code and loop through each time block (every 30 seconds) to count overlaps as below dumbed down version of code, (*yes there is room to optimize by further partition the data into days or even hours, so time blocks won't loop thru unnecessary data*)

```py
    all_time_blocks = {}
    time_block = date_from
    while time_block <= date_to:
        counter = all_time_blocks.setdefault(time_block, 0)
        for call in calls:
            if call[0] <= time_block <= call[1]:
                counter += 1
        all_time_blocks[time_block] = counter
        if counter > high_watermark:
            high_watermark = counter
        # advance the time block
        time_block = time_block + relativedelta.relativedelta(seconds=30)
```

is it possible to generate those 30 second blocks in query and group by **generated period blocks intersecting the call durations**?

like

```
group_by, count
2023-09-01 00:00:00 2023-09-01 00:00:30, 1
2023-09-01 00:00:30 2023-09-01 00:01:00, 3
2023-09-01 00:01:00 2023-09-01 00:01:30, 7
...
2023-09-30 23:59:30 2023-10-01 00:00:00, 0
```

The closest I could find is this answer, but the grouping logic is a bit different as it is grouped by the generated period key, but I need grouped by the period intersect with the actual start and end.

[Group by half hour interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283244/group-by-half-hour-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a series of timestamp values using a recursive CTE, and then join it to your table with the `start` and `end` columns.

It would look like this:

```
with recursive cte as (   
  select '2023-09-01 00:00:00' as timestamp   
  union   
  select timestamp + interval 30 second   
  from cte   
  where timestamp < '2023-09-30 23:59:30'
) 
select * from cte 
join mytable on cte.timestamp between mytable.start and mytable.end;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL's implementation of recursive CTE's has a rather low limit to the number of iterations.

> ERROR 3636 (HY000): Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

You could try to increase that, but I don't think it's wise to increase it to 86,400, which is the number of 30 second intervals you'd need for 30 days.

So the more optimized way of doing this is to create a temporary table and fill it with the timestamp values, then join that table to your table. It's a simple matter to do that with a loop in any scripting language.

```
select c.timestamp, c.count
from (
    select t.timestamp, count(*) as count
    from all_timestamps as t
    join mytable on t.timestamp between mytable.start and mytable.end
    group by t.timestamp
) as c
order by count desc
limit 1;
```

You can use the CTE solution with only SELECT privilege, even on a read-only instance.

To create a temporary table, you must have the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE privilege.

Comment: hmmm I am just dipping into a production monitoring system's DB, I only have read access.

Comment: I'd talk to the DBA who is responsible for this database, present your problem, and see if they can suggest a solution.